# Как идут Java и Kotlin для разработки мобильных приложений и игр?

Tags: java, unity3d, kotlin

Я читал кучу тем по этому вопросу, но есть другие вопросы от меня уже.

1. Какие преимущества дает знание и котлина и джавы? И нужен ли Kotlin вообще?
2. Можно ли создавать игры на юнити, зная джаву(или джаву + котлин)?
3. На какой платформе в целом можно создавать игры на J. + K.?
4. Можно ли на этих языках по отдельности или вместе, создавать 3D игры?

Comment: Отвечу на первый вопрос. Остальные к геймдевщикам)
Котлин дает меньше возможностей допустить ошибку.
Количество кода меньше на 30-40% по сравнению с Java.

Comment: Если говорить о `Unity3d`, то забываем про `Java` и узнаём про `C#`. Поддежки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Основное назначение Kotlin сделать работу с кодом более удобной и безопасной. Есть еще подобный ему язык Groovy, который выполняет примерно ту же роль. Оба языка выполняются над JVM и в конечном итоге компилируется в Java байт-код. Нет ничего, чего нельзя было бы сделать в Java без помощи Kotlin, поэтому он не обязателен. Но желателен, хотя бы по той причине, что активно используется в мобильной разработке.

Основные языки для Unity это C# и UnityScript, который основан на JS.
Поэтому знания Java и Kotlin могут только помочь понимать C#.

На Java и Kotlin можно создавать игры на любые платформы, но в основном это мобильная разработка игр под Android или браузерные игры. Создавать и распространять игры на Desktop из Java гораздо сложнее из-за особенностей Java, по крайней мере даже средние проекты можно [пересчитать по пальцам](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Java_platform_games) и я не знаю ни одного AAA проекта.

Думаю ответы выше отвечают и на четвертый вопрос.